# Basic Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

We wish to color p chairs arranged on a round carrousel using b colors. Two colorings are
considered identical if one can be obtained from the other by rotating the carrousel. Compute
the number of (dierent) ways to color the chairs, and use your answer to deduce FLT

Answer (score 0):

Of course... FLT refers to the "little" theorem, not the "last" one.

If we at first imagine the chairs to just be a row then there are $b^p$ ways of colouring this row of chairs. There are however b ways of colouring with the same colour. Thus there are $b^p - b$ ways of colouring the chairs in such a way that at least two different colours appear. If $p$ is assumed to be prime, then one can check that all rotations of such a colouring (with at least two different colours appearing) are distinct, thus there are $p$ of them. Thus there are $\frac{b^p-b}{p}$ different such equivalence classes of colourings with at least two colours appearing, and in total there are $$\frac{b^p-b}{p} + b$$ such.